# Let $A$ is a real matrix of order $n$. Prove $det(det(A))=(det(A))^{n}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I saw a solution to the problem **A is invertible prove $adj(adj(A))=det(A)^{(n-2)}\times A$** in which they used the identity:

$adj(adj(A))=((A^{-1})^{-1})\times det(A^{-1})\times(detA)^{(-1)}\times det(det(A))$

I didn't understand why
$det(det(A))=(det(A))^n$. The outcome of det() is a scalar and $det(k)=k$ when $k$ is scalar, so if to follow these rules, shouldn't $det(det(A))=det(A)$?
thank you everyone for your help!

Comment: Which other problem are you getting that identity from?

Comment: i'll update my post in a minute with the original problem, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you need to resolve what is meant by $\det(\det(A))$.  Since $\det(A)$ is a scalar, the principle ways to interpret $\det(A)$ are either as a $1 \times 1$ matrix, and thus effectively a scalar, or as $\det(A) I$, where $I$ is the $n \times n$ identity matrix.  In this latter case, $\det(A) I$ has $\det(A)$ as every diagonal entry, and zeroes everywhere else.  Therefore, $\det(\det(A)I)$ will be the product of it's $n$ diagonal entries, all equal to $\det(A)$.  Thus

$\det(\det(A) I) = (\det(A))^n. \tag 1$

Comment: For this $A$ must be non singular.

Comment: @Abhishek:  why?

Comment: because if A is singular , then $det(A)=0$

Comment: @Abhishek:  right.  And so, for example, $\det(det(A)I) = \det(0 I) = 0 = 0^n$.  Also, glad you got it.  No problemo, Senor!

Comment: Happy holidays from the virtual Med!

Comment: @copper.hat:  same to you my friend!